# SQL master-detail tables - better UPDATE or DELETE+INSERT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

We have an internal software based on an SQL-server DB with a master table and multiple joined tables. The nature of data we store is quite difficult to describe, but suppose we have a customers table with some joined tables: orders, shipments, phone-logs, complaints, etc.

We need to sync this software with an external one that has its own DB (with the very same structure) and produces an XML file with updated information about our "customers" (one file per customer). Updates may be in the master table and/or in 0 to *n* joined tables.

To import these files, one option is to query all the involved tables and compare them with the XML file, possibly adding-updating-deleting rows.

This would require a lot of coding.

Another option is to completely delete all data for the given customer (at least from the joined tables) and insert them again.

This would be not so efficient.

Please consider that the master table has 13 fields and there are about 6 tables with 3 to 15 fields.

In this app, we mainly use LINQ.

How would you proceed?

PS: I noticed a few answers on this subject here on StackOverflow, but almost all concern (single rows in) single tables.

Answer (score 0):

For a scenario where I have a lot of join and lots of rows I prefer to update and make logical deletes. Example I have millions of customers and happens I have dozens tables with millions rows with FK poiting to customer ID. Trying to delete a customer can take several minutes.

For your particular scenario I can use a flag in each pertinent table to tell me: This rows was already synchronized, the row was inserted as is pending exportation, the rows is pending a delete or the rows was exported to xml in the past but was updated.

For exports:

It can make easy to query just the rows pending to be iserted, updated or deleted and ignore rows are up to date.

For imports:

If the other system don't have this facility there's a little trick you can do. Add a "external ID" column to fast search your database and identify the rows originated from that external source.
Even using this trick can be a pain to find if only that phone number was updated int that large table. For those extreme cases you can use a hash computed column to quickly identify if the two rows are different and update the entire (at least the common column) row.

Comment: Thank you Jean for your answer.
Data is never exported from our application. Our app is mainly read-only, with data periodically updated by the 3rd party app (through xml).
And of course each xml file contains all data about a single customer (both data I already have in my db and data I need to add/edit/delete).
So every time a file comes in, I cannot tell what I should update, unless I compare each and every row.
It's not clear to me how can I use flags to handle all this.

Comment: Flags are only usefull for exports (a shame the other system cannot tell you what's being updated, inserted, deleted) and for logical deletion. For imports only you can create the "external ID" and if the table is large use also a hash column to find out if there are one update at all. You can even hash code the XML file to check if there are any alteration in the file compared with the previous version

Answer (score 0):

An idea (considering you do this at database server side):

- Build tables out of the customer xml. It can be temporary table or in-memory table.
- Create SELECT queries to find new, updated, deleted data. These select queries would join the tables in your database and the table built from the customer xml. The output of the join would tell whether you have new records, updated records, deleted records or mix of it.
- Run insert, update, delete accordingly.